# How to get *actual* frame size for UIScrollView in UINavigationController in iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiscrollview, ios7

So it appears that the view frame in navigation controllers iOS 7 is defined rather differently (in my opinion, strangely) as compared to iOS 7...

**EXAMPLE:** Imagine a UIViewController that contains a UIScrollView (`self.scrollView`) that fills the entirety of `self.view` and with struts and springs so that it always fills `self.view`. Now embed that UIViewController in a UINavigationController with the navigation bar kept visible.

In iOS 6, I observe the following:

- `self.view.frame.origin` = `(0.0, X)` where `X` = height of status bar (that contains time, signal bars, etc. = `20.0`)
- `self.view.frame.size.height` = `self.view.bounds.size.height` = overall height minus `self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height`
- `self.scrollView.frame.origin` = `self.scrollView.bounds.origin` = `(0.0, 0.0)`

In iOS 7, I observe the following:

- `self.view.frame.origin = (0.0, 0.0)`
- `self.view.frame.size.height` = `self.view.bounds.size.height` = overall height (i.e., no reduction in height when embedded in navigation controller)
- `self.scrollView.bounds.origin` = `(0.0, -1 * self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)`, but `self.scrollView.frame.origin` = `(0.0, 0.0)`

My guess is that this is done so that content can continue underneath the navigation bar so that the navigation bar can display the *slightest* amount of blur + transparency a la iOS 7.

**QUESTION: How can I get the actual size (width x height) of `self.scrollView` in iOS 7 when it's embedded in a navigation controller, given the observations above, since `self.scrollView.bounds.origin` == `self.scrollView.contentOffset`? Do I simply have to write different code for iOS 6 v. iOS 7 and detect which version is running?**

I don't really want to assume that the screen is any certain size and hard-code it in, since that seems like bad form...

---

**UPDATE 1:** I've uploaded a sketch of what I'm trying to ask. Note that the correct answer in this case is `416.0`, which is easy to obtain in iOS 6, but I'm not sure how to obtain it in iOS 7 without resorting to assumptions.

[image: Screenshots, iOS 6 v. iOS 7 Layout]

Comment: Just to be clear, the area you asking for is *not* the "actual size (width x height)" of the scroll view; the frame is giving you the correct answer to that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is happening is the your `UITableView` is automatically being adjusted so that the content will be visible behind the `UINavigationBar` on iOS 7. This is done by changing the `contentInset` property found in `UIScrollView`. So to get the frame excluding the part behind the nav/status bar, you just need to account for the `contentInset`.

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.origin.y += self.tableView.contentInset.top
frame.size.height -= self.tableView.contentInset.top;
```

This code will also work on iOS 6 because `self.tableView.contentInset.top` will default to 0.

Comment: +1. My only note would be that using pull-to-refresh or other things that manipulate the contentInset could cause this to misbehave, depending on what the resulting frame is being used for.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS7, you need to set `UIScrollView.contentInset.bottom/top` according to `UIViewController.bottomLayoutGuide/topLayoutGuide.length`.

Comment: Hi: Doing this just seems to make the scroll view full screen (behind the navigation bar) so that the first item is occluded. Is there a way to simply get a CGRect of the non-occluded part of the scroll view? I'm fine with the content inset in iOS 7.

Comment: I guess the alternative question is: Should I override iOS 7's default layout strategy to implement a more iOS 6-like layout and then set `self.tableView.clipsToBounds = NO` so that the navigation bar's transparency effect stays?